# Finding a finite model

Tags: logic, model-theory

Hello I am having difficulty with this question, I am not even sure what strategy one would go about proving something like this:

> Suppose $L$ is a language which includes an infinite list $c_1,c_2,\cdots$ of constant symbols. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of sentences $\Gamma = \{c_i \neq c_j | i,j\in N, i < j\}$. Let A be a sentence such that $\Gamma \Rightarrow A$. Prove that $A$ has a finite model.

I am not sure whether I would prove this via a contradiction (i.e., assume $A$ has an infinite model, or if I show a finite model that works or some how assume that we can have an infinite model and then use some sort of compactness to show it can be finite. I am a little all over the place with this question, please any help would be great!

Comment: The proof that $\Gamma\implies A$ involves only a finite number of the constants.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can you elaborate a little more. Thank you for commenting though.

Comment: Construct a model $A$ in which all the constants which do not appear in the proof of $\Gamma\implies A$ are equal.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez wouldn't that mean the model only has one element?

Comment: Consider someting like $\exists x\exists y\exists z\colon x\ne y\land x \ne y\land y\ne z$. There are many ways to prove this, e.g. by exhibiting $c_1, c_{42}, c_{666}$ as three different objects. Then all other $c_i$ could be equal to one of these three. But yousurely cannot prove this $A$ with less than three distinct objects.